# How to convert the name of a historical time period in to a year/date in SPARQL?

Tags: python, sparql, data-modeling, dbpedia, wikidata

I am a beginner to SPARQL and I managed to implement a query that returns the historical time period (P2348) for when an item was created, examples of this are 'Bronze age', 'Mesolithic', 'Nguyen dynasty' etc. I also have other items that return a specific year for when they were created. I was wondering if there is any way to convert the historical periods into an approximate year instead of the name of a period. It obviously doesn't have to be accurate at all just a year in that time period.

Comment: not sure if I understand, you have an unknown query (why not showing it here, nobody wants to start from scratch), ok - and sometimes the time period is something like "Mesolithic" which you want to be replaced by some concrete year(s) instead? So, from where shall this data come from? Either provide some mappings from period to year manually or try to ask Wikidata for some years about those historical period entities. See https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q44155 - it contains some start and end time - clearly, this might not hold for all, it might simply not exists or some other property is used

Comment: once you got the years, create your replacement string via `BIND` and some string functions

Comment: here is a sketch (lots of things to do and/or optimize): `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?period ?periodLabel ?periodString {
  VALUES ?period {wd:Q44155}
  OPTIONAL {?period wdt:P580 ?start}
  OPTIONAL {?period wdt:P582 ?end}
  
  ?item wdt:P2348 ?period .
  
  BIND(CONCAT("from ", str(year(?start)), " to ", str(year(?end))) AS ?periodString)
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  }
limit 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an age you can query its start and end time. Here is an example:

```
select ?age ?age_name ?start_time ?end_time {
  ?age wdt:P31 wd:Q15401699.  # age is archeological age.
  ?age rdfs:label ?age_name. filter(lang(?age_name)='en').
  ?age wdt:P580 ?start_time.
  ?age wdt:P582 ?end_time.
}
```